# Outbound Messaging: ActionId

Tags: soql, standard-objects, workflowoutboundmessage

I'm investigating the use of Outbound messaging for some integrations we need to make with SalesForce.

[According to the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_wsdl.htm#i1473596), the outbound message includes an `ActionId` field which is a salesforce id. Does anyone know which custom object the `ActionId` is the primary key for and whether it is queryable using SOPI?

**Background**

I'd like to create a generic endpoint for all our outbound messages so we can use publish/subscribe to route the various notifications to interested applications. It would be useful if applications could subscribe to notifications based on the developer name of the action so I'd like to translate the `ActionId` into this value.

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation its id of the workflow rule::

*ActionId   string  The workflow rule (action) that triggers the message.*

you can not query Workflow's using SOQL, but you can run a listMetadata call against the MetaData API that will return a list of workflow rules and record ids

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listmetadata.htm

Comment: Could you post an example? I can't find the correct id when I list the workflows using this metadata api method

Comment: @AndySkirrow I am afraid not. can you find the record using the UI https://<INSTANCE>.salesforce.com/<ACTION_ID>?

Answer (score 1):

In v32.0 of the Tooling API [WorkflowOutboundMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowoutboundmessage.htm) was exposed. You can query this in the Tooling API using the ActionId as the WorkflowOutboundMessage.Id. From there you can determine which workflow outbound message started the process.

See also: [Possible to distinguish (from xml request) which outbound message/workflow trigger was called?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/158766/102)